# How to edit button highlight color in Plotly dropdown menu?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I added a dropdown menu to my Python Plotly chart (Plotly 3.6.1). Now, I'd like to change the highlight color of the button (e.g. on hover) from default white to a different color. Is there any way to do this? Looking at the Plotly reference of the 'updatemenus' object, there doesn't seem to be a property to edit the highlight color.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you provide a [MCVE]? It will help others to answer your question and increase the chance to get an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the docs: https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/#style-buttons

Maybe you'll find a possibility to design your button how you want.